# Linux Mint 15 screen settings(brightness control)

Tags: linux-mint

How do you adjust the screen brightness on Linux Mint? Do I need a special app for it the way you do for the screen lock?

Comment: Normally it is Fn+F7, or something like this.

Answer (score 4):

Two options (mint 17.1):

1. Go to menu -> power managment.
2. Use terminal to download xbacklight, e.g.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xbacklight
   ```

Type `xbacklight` and see available commands.
I used `xbacklight -inc 10` a few times till reached desired brightness.

Comment: Thanks! Power Management worked for me in Linux Mint 17.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone using Linux Mint 16 Petra , the settings are now under the name 'Screensaver & Lock settings'. Although I dont understand the reasoning behind the naming.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Function-keys for brightness (e.g. Fn+F7 as @MariusMatutiae mentioned), you can always do  it via the Settings-Menu

`AllSettings->Brightness&Locking`

Answer (score 0):

I went to Advanced Settings (Per Activity Power Management), and then click on Use Separate Settings. You should see the screen brightness bar you'e familiar with. I'm using Linux Mint 18 KDE.