# Linux Mint: Change screen brightness using the keyboard

Tags: linux, linux-mint

On Linux Mint, I know that I can change the brightness by using

> menu -> power management, see [Linux Mint 15 screen settings(brightness control)](https://superuser.com/a/906986/1192848).

On Windows, my keyboard would work using <kbd>F11</kbd> for "-" and <kbd>F12</kbd> for "+" (without additional <kbd>Fn</kbd> key).

How can I get this done with the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have installed the newer version of Linux Mint 20.1 on another laptop and there, I can just change my screen brightness using

- <kbd>Fn</kbd>(Function button)+<kbd>F1</kbd> for *"brightness-"* and
- <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> for *"brightness+"*.

The functions of the F-keys are written on the keys anyway. Perhaps it is just working because they happen to be at the right <kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd> place, since on my other laptop, they are at <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>/<kbd>F12</kbd>. Another difference which might be part of the problem: at the other laptop, the function button is enabled as the standard.

I still guess that it just about updating Linux Mint to 20.1 to get this feature on <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>, so that it will not matter what is written on the keys. Whoever has the issue even on Linux Mint 20.1, please comment.